# Url not displaying correctly in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my index.blade.php I have

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('admin\MenusController@create', 'Create a menu', array("class" => "btn btn-default", "role"=>"button")) }}
```

but when I click on the link I have this in my url

> laravel/public/admin/menus/create?class=btn+btn-default&role=button

instead of

> laravel/public/admin/menus/create

I also have the same problem with my edit

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('admin\MenusController@store', $menu->title, array($menu->id)) }}
```

I get this in the url

> laravel/public/admin/menus?3

instead of

> laravel/public/admin/menus/3/edit

Comment: I fixed the issue with my edit. I had admin\MenusController@store instead of admin\MenusController@edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your array as a fourth parameter.

The third parameter is the parameters in the URL.
Try this:

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('admin\MenusController@create', 'Create a menu', array(), array("class" => "btn btn-default", "role"=>"button")) }}
```

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you, but I just realized now that I kind of have the same problem with another url. I have updated my question to include it

Comment: @Chibi Do the very same thing. You have to "skip" the third parameter. as a third parameter send an empty array or null.